# Tuple/Lookup conundrum

Tags: c#, lookup

I have a list of plans and a list of contacts, and I have to check whether `contact.ProviderId` matches `plan.ProviderId`. If they match I need to store in a `contactUI` the `plan.Name`.

Provider to plan is a 0..1-to-many relationship, and that's why I couldn't use the `Dictionary` I tried at first instance.

For retrieving the list of object I need to call the DB. So I want to avoid calling it more than needed.

I came up with this

```
var offeredPlans = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
foreach (var plan in plans)
{
    // ....Some code...
    offeredPlans .Add(new Tuple<int, string>(providerId, plan.Name));
}

var compareTo = offeringPlans.ToLookup(pair => pair.Item1, pair => pair.Item2);

foreach(var contact in contacts)
{
    var plansAttachedTo = Check(providerId.Value, compareTo);

    foreach (var plan in plansAttachedTo)
    {
        // New contactUI with plan.Name as one of its properties 
    }
}
```

Being

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Check(int providerId, ILookup<int, string> plans)
{
    return offeringPlans.Where(p => p.Key == providerId).SelectMany(p => p);
}
```

Is this terrible or does it make sense?

1. I've never used before these classes (Tuple, Lookup...)
2. I would like my code to be the clearest I can even it it's not the cleverest of the solution I can think of which is not this case for sure, actually I realize now I could have done some kind of SQL joins, right? (but I would like to know if someone can point any obvious error in the current code).

**Edit**

The code inside the loop is this one (in this case I don't even omit code as I'm not sure if it's possible what you suggest p.s.w.g). I am using reflection as only some of the classes that inherit from plan have the ProviderId property.

```
foreach (var plan in plans)
{
    var offeringDetail = new OfferingDetail();

    if (plan.GetType() == typeof (OwnedProductSummary))
    {
        var productSummary = plan as OwnedProductSummary;

        offeringDetail = _offeringBLL.GetById(productSummary.OfferingID);
    }

    if (plan.GetType() == typeof (OwnedServiceSummary))
    {
        var serviceSummary = plan as OwnedServiceSummary;

        offeringDetail = _offeringBLL.GetById(serviceSummary.OfferingID);
    }

    // For the other types of summary will be 0
    var providerId = offeringDetail.ProviderID;

    offeredPlans .Add(new Tuple<int, string>(providerId, plan.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've gotten your code into a `ILookup` you can just call [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549314.aspx) property (which in C# is called with `[...]`) to get all values with a given key. So the `Check` can be entirely replaced by using the `ILookup` like this:

```
ILookup<int, string> plansLookup = ...
IEnumerable<string> plansForProvider = plansLookup[providerId]; // Finds all plans for this provider
```

However, it's not clear that you need to be creating the `List<Tuple<int, string>>` in the first place. You can just use Linq to generate your `ILookup` from scratch:

```
var plansLookup = 
    (from plan in plans
     let productSummary = plan as OwnedProductSummary
     let serviceSummary = plan as OwnedServiceSummary
     let offeringDetail =
         (productSummary != null) ? _offeringBLL.GetById(productSummary.OfferingID) :
         (serviceSummary != null) ? _offeringBLL.GetById(serviceSummary.OfferingID) :
         new OfferingDetail()
     select new 
     {
         offeringDetail.ProviderID,
         plan.Name
     })
    .ToLookup(x => x.ProviderId, x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Yes, I pasted the code before checking it as I thought it was relevant. But you're completely right I can create it from scratch

Comment: Maybe I talked too early in the last comment, I think in this case either it's not possible or it would be a very convoluted expression, right?

Comment: @mitomed Nah, it's not that bad. See my updated answer.

Comment: Agreed, apart from a small typo (for instead of from) it works perfectly fine and it's not as terrible as I imagined (fear I had as never got into queries using lets). Thanks very much, I really think you've improved the code a lot